# Iqueryable Intersect fails when applied twice

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a series of parameters stored in rows in the database, and I'd like to return rows that satisfy both input parameters.  The parameters come through in the URL, like "&msg_type=20560&status=101"

I have code that works fine, but only if there's one parameter.  If there are two, it empties out the results.  Here's my code:

```
IQueryable<long> sol_params = (from param in db.kb_solution_param_list
                           select param.solution_id).Distinct();

foreach (String key in Request.QueryString.Keys)
{
    String val = Request.QueryString[key];

    IEnumerable<long> sols = from param in db.kb_solution_param_list
                             where param.parameter_name == key && param.value == val
                             select param.solution_id;

    sol_params = sol_params.Intersect(sols);

}
```

And here's the status of the variables, as they go through the debugger:

```
Initial:
sol_params: 
    [250 , 251 , 252 , 253 , 254 , 255 , 256 , 257 , 258 , 259 , 260 , 261 , 262 , 263 , 264 , 265 , 307 , 332 , 336]

Foreach Loop:
key: msg_type val: 20560
sols:
    [250 , 251]
sol_params:
    [250 , 251]

key: status val: 101
sols:
    [250 , 252 , 253 , 254 , 255 , 256 , 257 , 258 , 259 , 260 , 261 , 262 , 263 , 265 , 266 , 267 , 268 , 269 , 270 , 271 , 272]

sol_params: 
    []
```

The output I would be expecting is sol_params: [250]

Am I missing something stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is because the second time round, sol_params ends up performing the Intersect with the *second* key but the *first* value... because of the way you're capturing variables in the implicit lambda expressions. Try this:

```
foreach (String key in Request.QueryString.Keys)
{
    String keyCopy = key;
    String val = Request.QueryString[key];

    IEnumerable<long> sols = from param in db.kb_solution_param_list
                 where param.parameter_name == keyCopy && param.value == val
                 select param.solution_id;

    sol_params = sol_params.Intersect(sols);   
}
```

Note the change to the `where` clause.

See Eric Lippert's blog posts on capturing loop variables ([part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx); [part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx)) for more information.

I would also try declaring `sols` as `IQueryable<long>` instead of `IEnumerable<long>` - otherwise it'll be bringing intermediate data back to the client, instead of executing it all in the database, which is what I assume you wanted.